# Conditional key/value in a ruby hash

Tags: ruby

Is there a nice (one line) way of writing a hash in ruby with some entry only there if a condition is fulfilled? I thought of

```
{:a => 'a', :b => ('b' if condition)}
```

But that leaves `:b == nil` if the condition is not fulfilled. I realize this could be done easily in two lines or so, but it would be much nicer in one line (e.g. when passing the hash to a function).

Am I missing (yet) another one of ruby's amazing features here? ;)

Comment: What do you want for `hash[:b]` when the condition is not met? In ordinary hash, you will get `nil` anyway if there is no matching key.

Comment: If you iterate over the hash, then you'll see `:b` set even if `condition` is false.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

**UPDATE Ruby 2.4+**

Since ruby 2.4.0, you can use the [compact](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-compact) method:

```
{ a: 'a', b: ('b' if cond) }.compact
```

**Original answer (Ruby 1.9.2)**

You could first create the hash with key => nil for when the condition is not met, and then delete those pairs where the value is nil. For example:

```
{ :a => 'a', :b => ('b' if cond) }.delete_if{ |k,v| v.nil? }
```

yields, for cond == true:

```
{:b=>"b", :a=>"a"}
```

and for cond == false

```
{:a=>"a"}
```

**UPDATE for ruby 1.9.3**

This is equivalent - a bit more concise and in ruby 1.9.3 notation:

```
{ a: 'a', b: ('b' if cond) }.reject{ |k,v| v.nil? }
```

Comment: You can shorten `(cond ? 'b' : nil)` to `('b' if cond)`. Interesting idea.

Comment: If I put the `.delete_if{ |k,v| v.nil? }` in a separate function, it's even shorter. Thanks!

Comment: But then you could argue it's not a one-liner. Not that I would, of course. :)

Comment: Note: compact will return nil if none of the keys are removed, rather than the original hash.  Probably better to use delete_if for most situations.

Comment: @Gripp: This is not true. See: 
```ruby
[1] pry(main)> {a: 1}.compact
=> {:a=>1}
```. It is true for `compact!` though.

Answer (score 64):

From Ruby 1.9+, if you want to build a hash based on conditionals you can use `tap`, which is my new favourite thing. This breaks it onto multiple lines but is more readable IMHO:

```
{}.tap do |my_hash| 
  my_hash[:a] = 'a'
  my_hash[:b] = 'b' if condition
end
```

Comment: I would put any non-conditional values in the starting hash. But yeah, this is the way I'd do it - it works even when you want nils as hash values, and is still very readable, unlike some of the solutions posted.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Here's my one-line version:
`{a: "animal"}.tap { |hash| hash[:b] = 'banana' if true }`

Comment: @CameronMartin Maybe, but it's also nice to "line things up" whether they are conditionally included or not.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter Seven years later I agree with you on this. I guess my coding style has changed.

Comment: "If I can change, and you can change, everybody can change." :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtDvmV4zr-Q

Answer (score 29):

>= Ruby 2.4:

```
{a: 'asd', b: nil}.compact
=> {:a=>"asd"}
```

Answer (score 25):

Interested in seeing other answers, but this is the best I can think up of for a one-liner (I'm also notoriously bad at one-liners :P)

```
{:a => 'a'}.merge( condition ? {:b => 'b'} : {} )
```

Comment: Hmm, nice idea, but that could get pretty ugly with more than one conditional entry…

Comment: You are right. I don't think you'll find a nice one liner for this. If it's complex enough that it'll be that ugly, it's probably complex enough to build the hash ahead of time. Just my 2¢. :)

Comment: I think this is better than the accepted answer because it won't interfere with any intentionally nil hash values.

Answer (score 13):

In Ruby 2.0 there is a double-splat operator (`**`) for hashes (and keyword parameters) by analogy to the old splat operator (`*`) for arrays (and positional parameters). So you could say:

```
{a: 'b', **(condition ? {b: 'b'} : {})}
```

Answer (score 12):

There's a lot of clever solutions in here, but IMO the simplest and therefore best approach is

```
hash = { a: 'a', b: 'b' }
hash[:c] = 'c' if condition
```

It goes against the OP's request of doing it in two lines, but really so do the other answers that only appear to be one-liners. Let's face it, this is the most trivial solution and it's easy to read.

Answer (score 2):

```
Hash[:a, 'a', *([:b, 'b'] if condition1), *([:c, 'c'] if condition2)]
```

This relies on the fact that `*nil` expands to vacuity in ruby 1.9. In ruby 1.8,  you might need to do:

```
Hash[:a, 'a', *(condition1 ? [:b, 'b'] : []), *(condition2 ? [:c, 'c'] : [])]
```

or

```
Hash[:a, 'a', *([:b, 'b'] if condition1).to_a, *([:c, 'c'] if condition2).to_a]
```

Comment: Cool, I like that! Any way of writing this a bit more natural / simpler?

Comment: If you want consistency, you can put some extra things: `Hash[*([:a, 'a'] if true), *([:b, 'b'] if condition1), *([:c, 'c'] if condition2)]` but this goes counter to simplicity.

Comment: That's not what I meant :D I am just thinking whether there is some way doing this with a more hash-like `=>` notation, but I can't come up with anything.

Comment: Actually, if you are using ruby 1.9, the trend is to express a hash with symbol keys like `{a: 'a'}`, which comes close to `[:a, 'a']`, rather than `{:a => 'a'}`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple conditions and logic that others will need to understand later then I suggest this is not a good candidate for a 1 liner. It would make more sense to properly create your hash based on the required logic.

Answer (score 1):

This one is nice for multiple conditionals.

```
(
  hash = {:a => 'a'}.tap {|h|
    h.store( *[(:b if condition_b), 'b'] )
    h.store( *[(:c if condition_c), 'c'] )
  }
).delete(nil)
```

Note that I chose nil as the "garbage" key, which gets deleted when you're done. If you ever need to store a real value with a nil key, just change the store conditionals to something like:

```
(condition_b ? :b : garbage_key)
```

then delete(garbage_key) at the end.

This solution will also keep existing nil values intact, e.g. if you had :a => nil in the original hash, it won't be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

My one-liner solution:

```
{:a => 'a'}.tap { |h| h.merge!(:b => 'b') if condition }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hash, hash_new = {:a => ['a', true], :b => ['b', false]}, {}
hash.each_pair{|k,v| hash_new[k] = v[1] ? v : nil }
puts hash_new
```

Answer (score -6):

```
eval("{:a => 'a' #{', :b => \'b\'' if condition }}")
```

or even

```
eval("{#{[":a => 'a'", (":b=>'b'" if ax)].compact.join(',')}}")
```

for more simple add conditions

Comment: never use eval for something ;)