# Conditional inclusion of a key-value pair in a hash

Tags: ruby, hashtable

Can someone help me shorten the following method? I began with this, which I liked just fine:

```
def self.some_hash
  { "foo" => "bar" }
end
```

Now I want to add an optional key. The tersest syntax I can think of is this:

```
def self.some_hash(some_key=nil)
  answer = { "foo" => "bar" }
  answer[some_key] = "yucky, long-winded syntax" if some_key
  answer
end
```

The modified method works, but I'm dissatisfied with waste of virtual ink. Is there a way to shorten it?  I realize one could employ a ternary operator on the hash literal, but that would force (I think) the repetition the `"foo" => "bar"` pair on each branch of the condition, which is also slightly less than pristine.

Comment: "help me shorten the following method" is a give away that this should be on codereview.stackexchange.com where they do reviews and help with refactoring and optimizing.

Comment: Sad to see this question closed, when it is really asking, "How do I conditionally include a key/value pair in a hash?". I wrote an answer elsewhere using [Ruby 2.0's double-splat operator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37474217/122087).

Comment: @PaulAJungwirth, I guess it was closed because I wanted merely to improve working code.  I might have instead made-up some garbage syntax and then stated that it wasn't working, and all would be well in SO.  That's a GREAT tip about the ** operator!  Thanks <--- discouraging  'thanks in a comment is another dumb, norm around here, but --> THANKS!

Comment: The fact that none of the answers mention the ** operator show that this question is relevant. However, it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750770/conditional-key-value-in-a-ruby-hash ... and it should have been closed for that reason.

Comment: This question is a specific question about the syntax of a programming language. It is clearly on topic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
def self.some_hash(some_key = nil)
  {"foo" => "bar"}.merge(some_key ? {some_key => "yucky, long-winded syntax"} : {})
end
```

Or, if modifying the original hash,

```
def self.some_hash(some_key = nil)
  {"foo" => "bar"}
  .tap{|h| h.merge!(some_key => "yucky, long-winded syntax") if some_key}
end
```

Or, maybe you can do it in a way close to your original:

```
def self.some_hash(some_key = nil)
  {"foo" => "bar"}
  .tap{|h| h[some_key] = "yucky, long-winded syntax" if some_key}
end
```

Comment: Oh.  That's real nice.  Short, like @Kyle, and clearer.  Also good because it includes, rather than removes, conditionally.  Thanks.

Comment: +1 for the first (functional) snippet, I'd stay as far of `tap` as possible (IMHO it promotes imperative, unclear code)

Comment: thanks.  also appreciate learning about .tap.  Meta question: thanks for editing my question.  is there some step I must take to accept the edit?

Comment: @danh As was corrected by steenslag, there was a typo in my answer. Please be aware to use the corrected version. For edits, it depend on who edits. I think steenslag has enough reputation points to edit by himself/herself. If a person without enough reputation edits, then it needs to be approved by others who have enough points to do that.

Comment: This will only work only if key-value pair is at the end of the hash, what about if my hash is like `{:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3}` and i want `:b => 2` conditionally at that place only

Answer (score 1):

I don't really like it but this is pretty terse (and confusing)

```
def self.some_hash(some_key=nil)
  Hash[[["foo", "bar"], [some_key, "some value"]].select(&:first)]
end
```

This may be a *little* better.

```
def self.some_hash(some_key=nil)
  {"foo" => "bar", some_key => "some_value"}.keep_if{ |k, _| k }
end
```

[Hash#keep_if](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-keep_if)

Comment: Thanks.  It's at least a +1 for brevity.  Will wait a bit to see what else is suggested.

Comment: @danh I added one more for you that I think is a little better.

Comment: I wish I could up-vote twice.  I think your second idea is clearer and short, but @sawa saves us from doing an add + conditional delete.  Never heard of keep_if, and appreciate learning that, too!