# omitting empty values while creating hash

Tags: ruby

I create a hash that has many keys and I want to omit the keys that have `nil` values:

```
h = {
  :key0 => val0,
  :key1 => val1, # I want to include this key only if val1 is not nil
  :key2 => val2
}
```

are there any nice ways to do it other than

```
if val1
  h = {
    :key0 => val0,
    :key1 => val1,
    :key2 => val2
  }
else
  h = {
    :key0 => val0,
    :key2 => val2
  }
end
```

something along the lines of

```
h = {
  :key0 => val0,
  :key1 => val1 if val1, # gives an error
  :key2 => val2
}
```

EDIT: thanks for the responses so far, really useful. Is there a way to define a hash literal without having to process it afterwards?

Comment: Check out this question, wrongly closed (imo) based on phrasing.  It's the same question with several good answers...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175958/conditional-inclusion-of-a-key-value-pair-in-a-hash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [Hash#keep_if](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-keep_if) method. The method deletes every key-value pair from hsh for which block evaluates to false.

```
h = { :key0 => 'val0',:key1 => nil,:key2 => 'val2',:key4 =>nil}


h.keep_if {|key,value| !value.nil?}
```

> {:key0=>"val0", :key2=>"val2"}

Answer (score 0):

The "delete_if"-method can remove certain elements by yielding to a block. If that block returns true for an element, that element will be removed. Your code should then look like the following in order to remove the elements with a value that is nil:

```
val0 = true
val1 = nil
val2 = true

h = {
  :key0 => val0,
  :key1 => val1, # I want to include this key only if val1 is not nil
  :key2 => val2
}

h.delete_if{ |key, val| val.nil? }

puts h #=> {:key0=>true, :key2=>true}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to do a select:

```
{ :key0 => 1, :key1 => nil }.select {|_,v| v } 
#=> { :key0 => 1 }
```

In this case, if `v` is 'falsey' (either `false` or `nil`), the pair is omitted.