# adding a hash to an array of hash if not null?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have a method that takes in many parameters, including attachment, which I want to include in the hash only if not null. Is there a way to write this without constructing hashes for both cases?
My current array of hash looks like this

```
messagehash = [{    :from => fromhash,
                    :content => contenthash,
                    :to => tohash, 
                    :sentDate => datetime.to_i, 
                    :isPrivate => false, 
                    :sourceInboxes => [sender.email], 
                    :subject => subject}]
```

Can I add a hash to the list if the condition is met?
  Something like this maybe

```
if attachment
  messagehash[0].attachment = attachment_hash
end
```

So that it can end up like this

```
messagehash = [{    :from => fromhash,
                :content => contenthash,
                :to => tohash, 
                :sentDate => datetime.to_i, 
                :isPrivate => false, 
                :sourceInboxes => [sender.email], 
                :subject => subject,
                :attachment => attachment_hash}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional key/value in a ruby hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750770/conditional-key-value-in-a-ruby-hash)

Comment: a little different, this is an array of hash, so I wasn't sure

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sure you can:

```
messagehash[0][:attachment] = attachment_hash if attachment
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, it seems like you have an array with only one element, a hash.  Is that what you want, or just a hash?

for example, what you have:

```
messagehash = [{    :from => fromhash,
                    :content => contenthash,
                    :to => tohash, 
                    :sentDate => datetime.to_i, 
                    :isPrivate => false, 
                    :sourceInboxes => [sender.email], 
                    :subject => subject}]
```

would require `messagehash[0][:from]`  to access `fromhash`
vs just `messagehash[:from]` if you omit the [] like so:

```
messagehash = {     :from => fromhash,
                    :content => contenthash,
                    :to => tohash, 
                    :sentDate => datetime.to_i, 
                    :isPrivate => false, 
                    :sourceInboxes => [sender.email], 
                    :subject => subject}
```

if you *do* intend to have the hash as the first element of an array, then something like:

```
messagehash[0][:attachment] = attachment_hash if attachment_hash
```

should work.  But I think you really just want to add an item to a hash (not an array of hashes as you mention above), so something like this would work
h:

```
messagehash = {    :from => fromhash,
                    :content => contenthash,
                    :to => tohash, 
                    :sentDate => datetime.to_i, 
                    :isPrivate => false, 
                    :sourceInboxes => [sender.email], 
                    :subject => subject}

messagehash[:attachment] = attachment_hash if attachment_hash
```