# syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting end

Tags: ios, ruby, fastlane, bitrise

I'm trying to add an if statement to "deliver" action of fastlane.

I use fastlane with bitrise and the problem I'm having is when I add the if statement to a working sentence it always throws this syntax error: "syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting end"

This is the code I have of the Fastfile:

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "TEST"
    lane :testEnv do

        deliver(
            app_version: ENV['APP_VERSION'],
            app_rating_config_path: "./fastlane/app_store_rating_config.json",
            submit_for_review: false,
            screenshots_path: "./fastlane/screenshots/",
            metadata_path: "./fastlane/metadata/",
            force: true,
            #overwrite_screenshots: true,
            price_tier: 0,
            build_number: ENV['BITRISE_BUILD_NUMBER'],
            precheck_include_in_app_purchases: false,
            copyright: "#{Time.now.year}",
            primary_category: "EDUCATION",
            secondary_category: "BOOKS",
            automatic_release: false,

            release_notes: {
                if ENV['RELEASE_NOTES_ES'] != nil
                    "es-ES" => ENV['RELEASE_NOTES_ES'],
                end
                if ENV['RELEASE_NOTES_EN'] != nil
                    "en-GB" => ENV['RELEASE_NOTES_EN'],
                end
                if ENV['RELEASE_NOTES_PT'] != nil
                    "pt-BR" => ENV['RELEASE_NOTES_PT'],
                end
                if ENV['RELEASE_NOTES_ZH'] != nil
                    "zh-Hans" => ENV['RELEASE_NOTES_ZH'],
                end
                if ENV['RELEASE_NOTES_CA'] != nil
                    "ca" => ENV['RELEASE_NOTES_CA'],
                end
            },

            privacy_url: {
                if ENV['PRIVACY_URL_ES'] != nil
                    "es-ES" => ENV['PRIVACY_URL_ES']
                end
                if ENV['PRIVACY_URL_EN'] != nil
                    "en-GB" => ENV['PRIVACY_URL_EN']
                end
                if ENV['PRIVACY_URL_PT'] != nil
                    "pt-BR" => ENV['PRIVACY_URL_PT']
                end
                if ENV['PRIVACY_URL_EN'] != nil
                    "zh-Hans" => ENV['PRIVACY_URL_EN']
                end
                if ENV['PRIVACY_URL_ES'] != nil
                    "ca" => ENV['PRIVACY_URL_ES']
                end
            },

            support_url: {
                if ENV['SUPPORT_URL_ES'] != nil
                    "es-ES" => ENV['SUPPORT_URL_ES'],
                end
                if ENV['SUPPORT_URL_EN'] != nil
                    "en-GB" => ENV['SUPPORT_URL_EN'],
                end
                if ENV['SUPPORT_URL_PT'] != nil
                    "pt-BR" => ENV['SUPPORT_URL_PT'],
                end
                if ENV['SUPPORT_URL_EN'] != nil
                    "zh-Hans" => ENV['SUPPORT_URL_EN'],
                end
                if ENV['SUPPORT_URL_ES'] != nil
                    "ca" => ENV['SUPPORT_URL_ES'],
                end
            },

            #APP METADATA INFORMATION
            name: {
                if ENV['DESCRIPTION_ES'] != nil
                    "es-ES" => ENV['APP_NAME'],
                end
                if ENV['DESCRIPTION_EN'] != nil
                    "en-GB" => ENV['APP_NAME'],
                end
                if ENV['DESCRIPTION_PT'] != nil
                    "pt-BR" => ENV['APP_NAME'],
                end
                if ENV['DESCRIPTION_ZH'] != nil
                    "zh-Hans" => ENV['APP_NAME'],
                end
                if ENV['DESCRIPTION_CA'] != nil
                    "ca" => ENV['APP_NAME'],
                end
            },

            description: {
                if ENV['DESCRIPTION_ES'] != nil
                    "es-ES" => ENV['DESCRIPTION_ES'],
                end
                if ENV['DESCRIPTION_EN'] != nil
                    "en-GB" => ENV['DESCRIPTION_EN'],
                end
                if ENV['DESCRIPTION_PT'] != nil
                    "pt-BR" => ENV['DESCRIPTION_PT'],
                end
                if ENV['DESCRIPTION_ZH'] != nil
                    "zh-Hans" => ENV['DESCRIPTION_ZH'],
                end
                if ENV['DESCRIPTION_CA'] != nil
                    "ca" => ENV['DESCRIPTION_CA'],
                end
            },

            keywords: {
                if ENV['KEYWORDS_EN'] != nil
                    "en-GB" => ENV['KEYWORDS_EN'],
                end
                if ENV['KEYWORDS_ES'] != nil
                    "es-ES" => ENV['KEYWORDS_ES'],
                end
                if ENV['KEYWORDS_PT'] != nil
                    "pt-BR" => ENV['KEYWORDS_PT'],
                end
                if ENV['KEYWORDS_ZH'] != nil
                    "zh-Hans" => ENV['KEYWORDS_ZH'],
                end
                if ENV['KEYWORDS_CA'] != nil
                    "ca" => ENV['KEYWORDS_ES'],
                end
            },

            submission_information: {
                add_id_info_uses_idfa: false,
                content_rights_contains_third_party_content: false,
                export_compliance_platform: 'ios',
                export_compliance_compliance_required: false,
                export_compliance_encryption_updated: false,
                export_compliance_uses_encryption: false,
                content_rights_has_rights: false
            },

            app_review_information: {
              first_name: "Name",
              last_name: "Surname",
              phone_number: "+34 99999999",
              email_address: "name@mail.com",
              demo_user: ENV['DEMO_USER'],
              demo_password: ENV['DEMO_PASS'],
            }
        )
    end
end
```

This is my complete Fastfile, the problem is that in my project we have a lot of targets for different clients, each of them with different languages. What I did was to save this information on environment varibles on the bitrise machine (they are defined on the bitrise yml).

As you see I'm trying to add different languages depending on the environment variable, if it exists write this language too, but it is not working. I don't exactly know where is the problem because when I have it without ifs, it works as this example:

```
description: {
                "es-ES" => ENV['DESCRIPTION_ES'],
                "en-GB" => ENV['DESCRIPTION_EN'],
                "pt-BR" => ENV['DESCRIPTION_PT'],
                "zh-Hans" => ENV['DESCRIPTION_ZH'],
                "ca" => ENV['DESCRIPTION_CA'],
        },
```

This piece of code works correctly.

I don't have so much knowledge about ruby syntax, so maybe with your help I can achieve this, it would save me lot of time.

**Thank you!**

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: Hi @JörgWMittag, maybe it's enough just with these lines:
    if ENV['DESCRIPTION_ES'] != nil
         "es-ES" => ENV['DESCRIPTION_ES'],
    end 
I use this webpage https://extendsclass.com/ruby-tester.html to see errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is **not valid ruby syntax**:

```
{
  if ENV['RELEASE_NOTES_ES'] != nil
    "es-ES" => ENV['RELEASE_NOTES_ES'],
  end
}
```

There are [several ways you could add conditional elements to a hash in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5750770/1954610), such as:

```
{}.tap do |my_hash| 
  my_hash[:a] = 'a'
  my_hash[:b] = 'b' if condition
end
```

Or:

```
{:a => 'a'}.merge( condition ? {:b => 'b'} : {} )
```

Or:

```
hash = { a: 'a', b: 'b' }
hash[:c] = 'c' if condition
```

...But for your use case, since all you're trying to do is delete hash elements with a `nil` value, I would make use of [`Hash#compact`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-compact):

```
release_notes: {
  "es-ES" => ENV['RELEASE_NOTES_ES'],
  "en-GB" => ENV['RELEASE_NOTES_EN'],
  "pt-BR" => ENV['RELEASE_NOTES_PT'],
  "zh-Hans" => ENV['RELEASE_NOTES_ZH'],
  "ca" => ENV['RELEASE_NOTES_CA']
}.compact
```

Comment: Yes it is exactly what I need, thank you very much!!